# What are the laws regarding compiling SE answers and selling them for money?

Tags: intellectual-property, civil-law, theft

Thanks to user @Abcd for pointing this out. It seems that there are some [books](https://books.google.com/books?id=WjhRDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT17&lpg=PT17&dq=fluorobutane+with+alcoholic+KOH&source=bl&ots=XaVTOB8s9I&sig=TVpF4TAW3iNScdvTtdz4Z9GHCyM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiqm5-Ujb_aAhWLr48KHUiAAD0Q6AEITTAI#v=onepage&q=fluorobutane%20with%20alcoholic%20KOH&f=false) floating around the internet, selling for $4.61, that are compilations of SE answers. What are the laws regarding this, and what makes them legal/illegal (i.e. attribution)?*

*Meta posts on this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273989/are-these-ebooks-that-copy-from-se-illegal, https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4217/is-publication-of-chem-se-stuff-in-the-form-of-e-books-legal. As a further note, I'm not looking for whether its legal, I'm looking for **what makes it legal/illegal** and **where in civil law is it mentioned**.

Comment: Do you have a particular jurisdiction in mind?

Comment: @phoog United States (international law is OK also)

Comment: See also [Somebody scraped our answers and sold them as a book](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10581/somebody-scraped-our-answers-and-sold-them-as-a-book). It seems that extensive sample pages (not just "snippets") were published online without the licence and attribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they're attributing the material to SE, it should be fine. SE content is copyrighted but licensed under [Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).